# Connect to server with connect async

Tags: c#, exception, windows-8, windows-store-apps, async-await

Is there any possible that I can ensure that the application does not fall if app can not connect to the server using `await socket.ConnectAsync(server)` I get this exc:

[image]

But the biggest problem is I get this exception only occasionally and randomly. Try and catch completely unresponsive and applications fall. So I need something if I cannot connect firts time dont go to exception but try it again.

My code:

```
public async Task _connect(string token, string idInstalation, string lang)
{
    try
    {
        if (token != null)
        {
            socket.SetRequestHeader("Token", token);
            socket.SetRequestHeader("Lang", lang);
            socket.SetRequestHeader("idInstallation", idInstalation);
        }
        await socket.ConnectAsync(server);

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Connected");

        writer = new DataWriter(socket.OutputStream);
        messageNumber = 1;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        var dialog = new MessageDialog("Cannot connect to UNIAPPS server", "Error").ShowAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your application actually crashes? Isn't it just the debugger catching all exceptions? Have you tried to run your code without the debugger?

Comment: Ok I will try it without the debugger.